# How to show that Yetter-Drinfeld condition is equivalent to the condition of $H$-action commutes with braiding?

Tags: representation-theory, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $H$ be a bialgebra and ${}_H^H YD$ the category of Yetter-Drinfeld modules over $H$. It is said that Yetter-Drinfeld condition is equivalent to the condition of $H$-action commutes with braiding.

Suppose that 
$$
\Psi:  v\otimes w   \mapsto   v_{(-1)}.w \otimes v_{(0)}
$$
is a morphism of $H$-modules. Then for $h \in H$, we have 
$$
\Psi(h.(v \otimes w)) = h.(\Psi(v \otimes w)).
$$
The right hand side is
$$
h.( (v_{(-1)}.w )\otimes v_{(0)} ) = h_{(1)}.( (v_{(-1)}.w ) ) \otimes h_{(2)}.( v_{(0)} ).
$$
The left hand side is
$$
\Psi( h_{(1)}.v \otimes h_{(2)}.w ) = ( h_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)}.( h_{(2)}.w ) \otimes h_{(1)}.v )_{(0)}.
$$
But the equation 
$$
h_{(1)}.( (v_{(-1)}.w ) ) \otimes h_{(2)}.( v_{(0)} ) = ( h_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)}.( h_{(2)}.w ) \otimes h_{(1)}.v )_{(0)}                                 \quad (1)
$$
is slightly different from the Yetter-Drinfeld condition
$$
h_{(1)} v_{(-1)} \otimes h_{(2)}.v_{(0)} = ( h_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)} h_{(2)} \otimes (h_{(1)}.v)_{(0)}.  
$$
Since $V$ is an $H$-module, (1) is the same as
$$
( h_{(1)} v_{(-1)} ).w \otimes h_{(2)}.( v_{(0)} ) = ( ( h_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)} h_{(2)} ).w \otimes ( h_{(1)}.v )_{(0)}.
$$
But how to remove $w$ in the above equation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide a reference where this claim can be found?